# Which windows docker base image use for .net 3.5 wcf application

Tags: docker, wcf, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize legacy .Net 3.5 WCF applications using docker. I am not able to successfully run the container.

I have tried the following base images

microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5
microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to adopt the official images to dockerize the WCF.  There are some official Docker images published in the DockerHub.
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-wcf/?tab=description
In addition, here are some samples of Dockerizing WCF service, either IIS-hosted or self-hosted.
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/tree/master/samples/wcfapp
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your time @Abraham Qian but the above docs not mentioning anything related to .net 3.5 images, all images available seems to be 4.x